# one-dimensional Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, finance

> Let ($W_t$) denote a standard one-dimensional Brownian motion with $W_0 = 0$,
>   and let $M_t = \max W_s$ denote the running maximum process of $W$.
>   Let $m_t = \min W_s$ denote the minimum of $W$ at time $t$.
>
> Compute the
>   expected range of $W: E(M_t − m_t)$
>
> (Hint: use symmetry).

Answer (score 2):

$$-m_t = -\inf\limits_{0\leq s \leq t}W_s = \sup\limits_{0\leq s \leq t} (-W_s) \sim M_t \sim |W_t|$$
So,
$$E(M_t - m_t) = 2E(|W_t|) =\sqrt{\frac{8t}{\pi}}$$

Comment: thanks! I know that M_t=max (W_s), but how do you know sup (−Ws)∼M_t?

Comment: One can easily show that $-W_s \sim W_s$. But more, $-W_s$ is again a Brownian motion.

Comment: what is the best way to show that −Ws∼Ws?

Comment: $P(-W_s \leq x) = P(W_s \geq -x) = P(W_s \leq x)$, where the last equality follows from symmetry of normal distribution.

Comment: It is very clear! Thanks!